# how to get unique values from 2d array whille removing duplicate which contains elements from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I've array like this

```
const data=[ [aa, bb, cc], [aa, dd, cc], [aa, bb, cc], [aa, ee, cc], [aa, ff, cc], [aa, dd, cc]]
```

and another array like this

```
const array2=[bb, dd, ee]
```

I want to convert it into like this:

```js
const data=[ [aa, bb, cc], [aa, dd, cc], [aa, ee, cc] ]
```

I tried like this:

```js
const unique = [...data.reduce((cache, curr) => {
      let key = JSON.stringify(curr);
       if (!cache.has(key)) cache.set(key, curr)
       return cache;
     }, new Map()).values()]
```

but it's not working properly.It is giving value from array 2 also

P.S. thank you.

Comment: why belongs `[aa, ff, cc]` not to the result? For what you use `array2`?

Comment: that's what the expecting output. whatever in the array2, only that array I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, you could use an `areEqual` function to determinate if elements in `data` are equal, and an `isValid` function to verify if element to put in result is valid (compared to `array2`) like this example:

```js
const data=[ ["aa", "bb", "cc"], ["aa", "dd", "cc"], ["aa", "bb", "cc"], ["aa", "ee", "cc"], ["aa", "ff", "cc"], ["aa", "dd", "cc"]]

const array2=["bb", "dd", "ee"]

function areEqual(array1, array2) {
   let result = true;
   array1.forEach(val => {
      if(!array2.includes(val)) result = false;
   })
   return result;
}

function isValid(array1) {
   let result = false;
   array2.forEach(val => {
      if (array1.includes(val)) result = true;
   })
   return result;
}
let result = [];
data.forEach(val => {
    if (isValid(val)) {
       let insertit = true
       result.forEach(res => {
          if(areEqual(val, res)) insertit = false
       })
       if(insertit) result.push(val)
    }
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter with a `Set`.

```js
const
    data = [['aa', 'bb', 'cc'], ['aa', 'dd', 'cc'], ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'], ['aa', 'ee', 'cc'], ['aa', 'ff', 'cc'], ['aa', 'dd', 'cc']],
    include = ['bb', 'dd', 'ee'],
    unique = data
        .filter(a => a.some(v => include.includes(v)))
        .filter(
            (s => a =>
                (j => !s.has(j) && s.add(j))
                (JSON.stringify(a))
            )
            (new Set)
        );

console.log(unique);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I do'nt want last array containing 'ff', expecting output is only that array which conatins value from array2

Comment: why not? do you have a rule for it?

Comment: what for is `array2`?

Comment: to filter the values from array2

Comment: do you have an example of the result of diltering by `array2`?

Comment: please have a look to the first filter. btw, you have changed the values of `array2`.